# Как можно разместить линию между блоками?

Tags: html, css, css3

Каким образом можно разместить их между блоками?

[image: ht]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1009648/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8

Comment: В моем случае нужно другое решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Каким образом можно разместить их между блоками?

А Вы просто нарисуйте эту линию на фоне родителя с помощью `linear-gradient`

[Результат на CodePen](https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/pozPEbp)

Результат здесь:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #F8F9FB linear-gradient(#828385, #828385) left / 100% 2px no-repeat;
}

.item {
  margin: 10px 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Все результаты</div>
  <div class="item">Места и заведения</div>
  <div class="item">Мероприятия</div>
  <div class="item">Акции</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ого, спасибо. Не знал об этой команде

Comment: @МансурВаситов, если ответ помог, можете пометить его решением. Скриншоот галочки отметки: https://bit.ly/2Hss3VA