# Как вставить горизонтальные линии между объектами?

Tags: html, css, scss

Сверстал 5 шагов. В макете между ними есть линии, которые их разделяют. Каким образом я смогу реализовать эти линии и вставить их между шагами? При этом, в макете видно, что эти линии свободно проходят между границами контейнеров.[image: Как есть у меня][image: Как надо сделать][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.steps {
  width: 1180px;
  height: 455px;
  padding-top: 110px;
  margin: auto;
}

.steps-header {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Rubik';
  font-style: normal;
  color: #444444;
}

.container-navigation__step {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.navigation__step {
  padding-top: 67px;
  width: 220px;
  height: 217px;
}

.step-number {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-family: 'Rubik';
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: #E73D66;
}

.what-to-do__step {
  padding-top: 27px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 26px;
  font-family: 'Rubik';
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: #444444;
}

.text-step {
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-family: 'Rubik';
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: #444444;
}
```

```html
<div class="steps">
        <h2 class="steps-header">КАК ЗАБРАТЬ ПИТОМЦА ДОМОЙ?</h2>
        <div class="container-navigation__step">
            <div class="navigation__step">
                <h3 class="step-number">1</h3>
                <h4 class="what-to-do__step">Выберите питомца</h4>
                <p class="text-step">В нашем приюте содержится более 60 собак</p>
            </div>
            <div class="navigation__step">
                <h3 class="step-number">2</h3>
                <h4 class="what-to-do__step">Оставьте
                    заявку</h4>
                <p class="text-step">Через сайт или связавшись с нами любым удобным для вас способом</p>
            </div>
            <div class="navigation__step">
                <h3 class="step-number">3</h3>
                <h4 class="what-to-do__step">Пройдите
                    собеседование</h4>
                <p class="text-step">Мы заботимся о наших питомцах и отдаем их только в хорошие руки</p>
            </div>
            <div class="navigation__step">
                <h3 class="step-number">4</h3>
                <h4 class="what-to-do__step">Познакомьтесь
                    с собакой</h4>
                <p class="text-step">Приезжайте к нам в приют, что бы в живую увидеть вашего питомца</p>
            </div>
            <div class="navigation__step">
                <h3 class="step-number">5</h3>
                <h4 class="what-to-do__step">Забирайте
                    друга домой</h4>
                <p class="text-step">Мы поможем вам с транспортировкой</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1009648/178988

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.steps {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.container-navigation__step {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
}

.navigation__step > * {
  padding: 0 .5em;
}

.step-number {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #E73D66;
  padding-inline: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: .25em;
  align-items: center;
}

.step-number::before, .step-number::after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.navigation__step:first-child .step-number::before,
.navigation__step:last-child .step-number::after {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="steps">
  <h2 class="steps-header">КАК ЗАБРАТЬ ПИТОМЦА ДОМОЙ?</h2>
  <div class="container-navigation__step">
    <div class="navigation__step">
      <h3 class="step-number">1</h3>
      <h4 class="what-to-do__step">Выберите питомца</h4>
      <p class="text-step">В нашем приюте содержится более 60 собак</p>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation__step">
      <h3 class="step-number">2</h3>
      <h4 class="what-to-do__step">Оставьте заявку
      </h4>
      <p class="text-step">Через сайт или связавшись с нами любым удобным для вас способом</p>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation__step">
      <h3 class="step-number">30</h3>
      <h4 class="what-to-do__step">Пройдите собеседование
      </h4>
      <p class="text-step">Мы заботимся о наших питомцах и отдаем их только в хорошие руки</p>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation__step">
      <h3 class="step-number">4</h3>
      <h4 class="what-to-do__step">Познакомьтесь с собакой</h4>
      <p class="text-step">Приезжайте к нам в приют, что бы в живую увидеть вашего питомца</p>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation__step">
      <h3 class="step-number">5</h3>
      <h4 class="what-to-do__step">Забирайте друга домой</h4>
      <p class="text-step">Мы поможем вам с транспортировкой</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Не знаете, как убрать полоску перед цифрой 1 и после цифры 5?

Comment: @syrex, `.step-number:first-child::before, .step-number:last-child::after { content: none; }`.

Comment: К сожалению, не работает. Я вставляю это после Вашей последней строчки (где step-number after, before), после чего линии пропадают вовсе, а цифры встают по левой границе. Может, я как-то не так делаю?

Comment: @syrex, а ну да... `.navigation__step:first-child .step-number::before, .navigation__step:last-child .step-number::after { visibility: hidden; }` - вот так для этого ответа. А для соседнего можно и content убирать.

Comment: @qwerity, не знаю, кто вы, но для меня - герой :) Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Я б переписал полностью css, но мне лень было это делать, ибо css разметку я б по другому делал изначально. Поэтому держи заклёпку:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .steps {
                width: 1180px;
                height: 455px;
                padding-top: 110px;
                margin: auto;
            }
            .steps-header {
                font-weight: 500;
                font-size: 50px;
                line-height: 60px;
                text-align: center;
                font-family: 'Rubik';
                font-style: normal;
                color: #444444;
            }

            .container-navigation__step {
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                justify-content: center;
            }
            #rect{
                width: 1000px;
                height: 3px;
                position: absolute;
                background: #e73d66;
                z-index: -1;
                margin-top: 135px;
            }
            .navigation__step {
                padding-top: 67px;
                width: 220px;
                height: 217px;
            }
            .step-number {
                margin: 1em 46px;
                background: white;
                font-weight: 500;
                font-size: 50px;
                line-height: 40px;
                font-family: 'Rubik';
                font-style: normal;
                text-align: center;
                color: #E73D66;
                z-index: 10;
            }

            .what-to-do__step {
                padding-top: 27px;
                font-weight: 400;
                font-size: 22px;
                line-height: 26px;
                font-family: 'Rubik';
                font-style: normal;
                text-align: center;
                color: #444444;
            }

            .text-step {
                padding-top: 10px;
                font-weight: 300;
                font-size: 16px;
                line-height: 22px;
                font-family: 'Rubik';
                font-style: normal;
                text-align: center;
                color: #444444;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="steps">
            <h2 class="steps-header">КАК ЗАБРАТЬ ПИТОМЦА ДОМОЙ?</h2>
            <div class="container-navigation__step">
                <div id="rect"></div>
                <div class="navigation__step">
                    <h3 class="step-number">1</h3>
                    <h4 class="what-to-do__step">Выберите питомца</h4>
                    <p class="text-step">В нашем приюте содержится более 60 собак</p>
                </div>
                <div class="navigation__step">
                    <h3 class="step-number">2</h3>
                    <h4 class="what-to-do__step">Оставьте
                        заявку</h4>
                    <p class="text-step">Через сайт или связавшись с нами любым удобным для вас способом</p>
                </div>
                <div class="navigation__step">
                    <h3 class="step-number">3</h3>
                    <h4 class="what-to-do__step">Пройдите
                        собеседование</h4>
                    <p class="text-step">Мы заботимся о наших питомцах и отдаем их только в хорошие руки</p>
                </div>
                <div class="navigation__step">
                    <h3 class="step-number">4</h3>
                    <h4 class="what-to-do__step">Познакомьтесь
                        с собакой</h4>
                    <p class="text-step">Приезжайте к нам в приют, что бы в живую увидеть вашего питомца</p>
                </div>
                <div class="navigation__step">
                    <h3 class="step-number">5</h3>
                    <h4 class="what-to-do__step">Забирайте
                        друга домой</h4>
                    <p class="text-step">Мы поможем вам с транспортировкой</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.steps {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.container-navigation__step {
  display: flex;
}

.navigation__step {
  flex: 1 0 0px;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.step-number {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #E73D66;
}

.step-number::before, .step-number::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.step-number::before {
  margin-left: calc(-100% - .25em);
}

.step-number::after {
  margin-left: .25em;
}

.navigation__step:first-child .step-number::before,
.navigation__step:last-child .step-number::after {
  content: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="steps">
  <h2 class="steps-header">КАК ЗАБРАТЬ ПИТОМЦА ДОМОЙ?</h2>
  <div class="container-navigation__step">
    <div class="navigation__step">
      <h3 class="step-number">1</h3>
      <h4 class="what-to-do__step">Выберите питомца</h4>
      <p class="text-step">В нашем приюте содержится более 60 собак</p>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation__step">
      <h3 class="step-number">2</h3>
      <h4 class="what-to-do__step">Оставьте заявку
      </h4>
      <p class="text-step">Через сайт или связавшись с нами любым удобным для вас способом</p>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation__step">
      <h3 class="step-number">30</h3>
      <h4 class="what-to-do__step">Пройдите собеседование
      </h4>
      <p class="text-step">Мы заботимся о наших питомцах и отдаем их только в хорошие руки</p>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation__step">
      <h3 class="step-number">4</h3>
      <h4 class="what-to-do__step">Познакомьтесь с собакой</h4>
      <p class="text-step">Приезжайте к нам в приют, что бы в живую увидеть вашего питомца</p>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation__step">
      <h3 class="step-number">5</h3>
      <h4 class="what-to-do__step">Забирайте друга домой</h4>
      <p class="text-step">Мы поможем вам с транспортировкой</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```